# Python - Unable to rename a file with special characters in the file name

Tags: python, file, character, rename

I have a bunch of mp3 files that somehow have a special character in the 0th index. So the file name looks like this - ▶ Alone Tonight - Radio Edit - Above & Beyond .mp3

I want to be able to fix this. In python, when I list the file, it shows up like this:

```
'? Alone Tonight - Radio Edit - Above & Beyond .mp3'
```

All I want to do is to rename this file with the substring defined by `[2:len(filename)]`

However, when I do this:

```
newfilename = filename[2:len(filename)]
os.rename(filename,newfilename)
```

I get

> WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume
>   label syntax is incorrect

So what are my options? It looks like windows wont' recognize the special character. I am able to manually edit it, but not programmatically.

Comment: As a note, Python automatically chooses the length of the sequence as the end bound for slicing if it is ommitted, so you can simply do `filename[2:]` instead of `filename[2:len(filename)]`.

Comment: What does the filename look like if you list it with `os.listdir(u'/path/to/files')`. Note the `u` before the path. This makes the path a `unicode`. When the path is `unicode`, `os.listdir` returns unicode filenames.

Comment: u'\u25b6 Alone Tonight - Radio Edit - Above & Beyond .mp3'

Comment: Good. Try removing the file using the unicode filename.

Comment: That worked!!! Thanks. I have been searching high and low for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have better luck using the unicode name for the file.
To obtain the unicode name, pass a unicode path to `os.listdir`.

```
for filename in os.listdir(u'/path/to/files'):
    if filename.startswith(u'\u25b6'):
        os.rename(filename, filename[2:])
```

Note that using unicode may not always be quite enough to specify the filename (you may have to normalize the unicode), since more than one unicode code point sequence can have the same appearance and meaning. (See [unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence), and Ned Batchelder's [blog post on the subject](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201106/filenames_with_accents.html)).