# Special shell characters when opening in a file Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, escaping, character

I have an interesting problem that I couldn't solve by googling.

I'm trying to process each file inside of the directory. Some of the file names include special shell characters (`$`, `(`, `)` etc). A good example of such file name:

`FOO.-6.BAR.(nil).$0BAZ`

When I try to open this file in bash without any escaping I get an error `No matches found` therefore I **need** to escape it in a following fashion:

`FOO.-6.BAR.\(nil\).\$0BAZ`

As such it does open in bash (e.g. `cat`ing works).

However, the problem is that even when I escape the file name in exact same fashion in python's code I still get `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

I've also noticed that when I escape special characters (e.g. `f.replace('$', '\$')`) the final file name used in `open` is double prepending my slashes (`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FOO.-6.BAR.\\(nil\\).\\$0BAZ'`) even though when I print the file name by hand (`print f`) I get valid `FOO.-6.BAR.\(nil\).\$0BAZ`.

At this point I'm slightly out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried os.listdir('.') to see how the names may be formatted and then subsequently use that to open them?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Which python version are you using? Can you share your code? I've tried this without escaping and it worked well.

Comment: Yes. That's actually the method I'm using to iterate through each file inside of the directory, i.e. I'm using `os.listdir(directory)` to get a list of files and then process each one of them. The names themselves are unescaped.

I'm using Python 2.7 on OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape anything when opening the file from Python, because you aren't executing a shell command at all.

```
f = open("FOO.-6.BAR.(nil).$0BAZ")
```

The same is true of any file name returned by `os.listdir`:

```
for fname in os.listdir('.'):
    f = open(fname)
```

Comment: Yes, you're of course right! This was major brain fart on my part. I do get an error but it's because my `os.path.abspath` call on a current file is using script's own directory as root for the file (which is wrong because file is somewhere else).

Your example with processing files in current directory pushed me into solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve this by looking at your directory with `os.listfiles('/path/to/stuff')`. Your file in there will come back with the \x characters in there. Try to open that after it.

Potentially, depending on your further files, you may also want to use Unicode to look at the files. Do this using `os.listfiles(u'/path/to/stuff')`.

Also see [Python - Unable to rename a file with special characters in the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510562/python-unable-to-rename-a-file-with-special-characters-in-the-file-name) which is a post that has a similar problem.